# apache AuthBasic denying correct login

Tags: apache-2.2, http-basic-authentication, htpasswd

I created a vhost in apache with this config

```
Alias   /my    /srv/my

<Location /my>
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "private area"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/my/mypass
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I enter the url in browser, am asked for passwd but get access denied. All further request are denied without asking (cached?).

Prob is it wont accept my passwd, even I updated the passwd file so i am sure to use the correct one.

Comment: Did you generate `mypass` using `htpasswd`? Have you tried to use a rather simple password to exclude encoding issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I needed was:

```
<Directory "/srv/my">
    Options Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

I put pw file seperated from content.

ssl coming asap

Answer (score 3):

I'd use

```
<Location /my>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "private area"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/mypass
    Require valid-user
    SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
```

1. Keep your password file separated from the content.
2. Use encryption.

Did you saved passwords in plain text in `mypass`? If so, use `htpasswd`.

Comment: This should do it.  One thing to add; check for any errors in Apache's log related to the htpasswd file, such as a permissions issue.